# Why is there a loss of quality between programs executed in the Processing IDE and the same program executed in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, processing

I have been writing a Processing program in the Processing IDE, and I now need more functionality such as adding libraries with Maven, Gradle, etc. For that reason, I have been migrating from the Processing IDE to IntelliJ IDEA.

I have added Processing's core.jar to the classpath, and the program will execute without error.

The problem is that there seems to be a lack of quality when using IntelliJ. That is, everything renders just fine when using the Processing IDE, but after building with IntelliJ, everything renders with a major lack of quality as well as differences in text size. Attached below are code and images.

Processing IDE Code:

```
int headerHeight;
float x = 0;
float dim = 80;
boolean hasSurpassed = false;

void setup(){
  headerHeight = height/5;  
  fullScreen();
  background(255);
  print(headerHeight);
  noStroke();
  smooth();
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  drawHeader();
}

void drawHeader(){
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  strokeWeight(7);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  rect(0, 0, width, headerHeight);
  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  strokeJoin(ROUND);
  triangle(25, 191, 100, 25, 175, 191);
  fill(255);
  textSize(125);
  text("!", 81, 163);
  textSize(150);
  text("NOTIFICATION SYSTEM", 195, 166);  
  textSize(20);
  text("You have multiple pending deltas!", 208, 200);
  noStroke();
}
```

Output:

[image]

IntelliJ IDEA Code:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class NotificationSystem extends PApplet{

    private int headerHeight = 0;
    private float x = 0;
    private boolean hasSurpassed = false;

    public void setup(){
        background(255);
        headerHeight = height/5;
        noStroke();
    }

    public void settings() {
        fullScreen();
        smooth();
    }

    public void draw(){
        background(255);
        drawHeader();
    }

    private void drawHeader(){
        stroke(255, 0, 0);
        strokeWeight(7);
        fill(255, 0, 0);
        rect(0, 0, width, headerHeight);
        noFill();
        stroke(255);
        strokeJoin(ROUND);
        triangle(25, 191, 100, 25, 175, 191);
        fill(255);
        textSize(125);
        text("!", 81, 163);
        textSize(150);
        text("NOTIFICATION SYSTEM", 195, 166);
        textSize(20);
        text("You have multiple pending deltas!", 208, 200);
        noStroke();
    }

    public static void main(String[] passedArgs) {
        NotificationSystem notificationSystem = new NotificationSystem();
        PApplet.main(notificationSystem.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: IntellihJ IDEA Output]

I did not want to provide so much code as to post a Minimal, Complete, & Verifiable example, but I feel that you need to see both sets of code as to be able to replicate the problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Something to investigate: what renderer is each using? Is the default renderer perhaps different when you run via Intellij vs the Processing Editor?

Comment: @KevinWorkman How would I check which renderer I am using? Thank you.

Comment: There appear to be a bunch of functions and variables related to the renderer in the `PApplet` class: https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java

Comment: @KevinWorkman I just tried forcing both the original Processing sketch and the IntelliJ IDEA program to use the JAVA2D Renderer as well as the P2D Renderer. Both times, Processing IDE displayed the output correctly, and IntelliJ IDEA did not.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Do you have any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I just ran this on my own computer. I don't see any differences between Processing, Eclipse, and Intellij. What happens if you try a different computer, or a different version of the Processing library in Intellij?